# How this sequence is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given sequence $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}...+\dfrac{1}{2n-1}$

$a_{n+1}-a_{n} <0$

Which means its an decreasing sequence. But when i calculate first three terms they are not seems to portray  a decreasing sequence, may be i am computing them wrong. Someone correct me please.
$a_1=1$

$a_2=1+\frac{1}{3}=1.33$

$a_3=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}=1.53$

Comment: The sums don't all start at $1$, for example $a_2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @dxiv Could you elaborate to me please.

Comment: You wrote `a_2 = 1 + 1/3` but that's wrong because the first term is $\frac{1}{n}= \frac{1}{2}$, and the last term is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @dxiv ohh may b i am confusing with partial sums.

Comment: @could you tell me what will be first 3 terms ?

Comment: Just replace the "$\ldots$" dots with the fractions whose denominators go from $\,n\,$ to $\,2n-1\,$. For $\,n=3\,$ that means $\,2n-1=5\,$ so the sum is $\,a_3=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\,$.

Comment: @Rohan Don't call me sir man. I am just beginner in maths. And if i may ask are you from india?  Could you help me in my exam. I have entrance exam on 11 feb. IIT jam mathematical statistics.

Comment: You are still older than me, then. I am in second year of college and I don't know if I might be able to help you or not. And yes, currently in India!

Comment: I would say you are more experienced in maths. Thus i am not eligible to be called sir. Anyhow can i contact you somewhere quick  for an instant doubt or you prefer stack exchange ? But its so time consuming,writing question in latex then wait for a reply. Could you help me here a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

\begin{align} 
a_n = \frac1{n} +\frac1{n+1} +\frac1{n+2} + \ldots+ \frac1{n+(n-1)}\\
a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac1{n+2} +\ldots +\frac1{2n+1}\\
a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{n}=\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{2n}=-\frac1{2n(2n+1)}<0
\end{align}

Note that this aligns with your intuitions, but you have made some computational mistakes. Note that $$a_2=\frac12+\frac13 \neq 1 +\frac13$$ and $$a_3=\frac13+\frac14+\frac15=\frac{47}{60}$$ $$\neq 1+\frac13+\frac15$$

Comment: (+1) My answer is pretty much the same, but yours was first.

Answer (score 3):

Your computations are a bit off:
$$
a_1=\frac11
$$
$$
a_2=\frac12+\frac13
$$
$$
a_3=\frac13+\frac14+\frac15
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
a_n-a_{n+1}
&=\frac1{n}-\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+1}\\
&=\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+1}\\
&=\frac1{2n(2n+1)}\\[6pt]
&\gt0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Pretty much the same as Rohan's answer.